# How to fit a curve to a histogram in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, histogram, curve-fitting

I explored similar questions asked about the above topic but they couldn't help me to find a good curve to the following histogram.
For example in the output of the following code, the curve's peak is high (It has high kurtosis). How to solve this problem?

Code:

```
SumR = [1.02957968211466e+23,1.12316700832322e+16,1.01205904405943e+24,1.23183231736978e+22,1.71254955156886e+18,0,2.78888971554146e+16,1.06495767772703e+21,1.02761772773492e+24,2.56040885583339e+19,3.04201226469320e+21,1.12113264824989e+20,5.23573831147063e+18,1.95497792957160e+19,1.36150887360868e+19,4.41352571341253e+22];

h = histogram(SumR, 'FaceColor','g');  % SumR is a vector with dim 1x16.
numbins = h.NumBins; % In this example is 3.

 ...' figure out how to scale the pdf, to the area of the histogram.
[bincounts,binpos] = hist(SumR, numbins);
binwidth = binpos(2) - binpos(1);
histarea = binwidth*sum(bincounts);

...' kernel estimator.
[f,x,u] = ksdensity(SumR);
line(x, f*histarea, 'Color', 'g', 'LineWidth',2);
```

Output:

[image]

and also, consider the image below which peak of the curve should be like the red curve.

[image]

Comment: What's you criteria for a "good curve"? Should it be pinned to the peak of your data? You could draw a straight line between `[0,110]` and `[12,0]` which would satisfy that but it would be a terrible fit for your data... Please define "good" at least subjectively, preferably mathematically.

Comment: @Wolfie: It is edited and the red curve is my goal instead of its corresponding green curve.

Comment: It's better, but still not clear to me how you've fitted a curve to a single point - your question doesn't include a [mcve] (MRE), but presumably it's something like `[110, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` for bins 1 to 12? If so, what wouldn't the curve be sharper for instance? Or maybe not because you've got some small peaks in the green curve... Including a MRE would help a lot. It would also help to know what the curve is meant to demonstrate, maybe that's an easier question to answer than how to define the curve - would a (smoothed) line which joins the bars dot-to-dot style work?

Comment: Possibly related:  [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitdist.html) and [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/curve-fitting-and-distribution-fitting.html)

Comment: @Wolfie: A minimal example is created.

Comment: If the skewness and kurtosis are extreme enough, then this will be a challenge. However, the Johnson-Unbounded (SU) family may be best.  Using `skewness(SumR)` = 2.2421 and `kurtosis(SumR)` = 6.0745.  I'm trying to dig up a good reference on this. However, you're fitting to only 16 observations. The experts on this are at Stats.SE ([CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: See https://imgur.com/a/6gahsOJ.

Comment: Regarding the red line drawn in your image, I think the bin width is visually misleading. I suggest taking a quick look at a histogram made with a narrower bin width to verify the intuitive red line.